# I need the sum of two columns in a view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I found this code that goes through and prints out csv for both columns.  I later parse and count the two columns.  I want to count it here instead of printing and counting later.  I've been mucking around but couldn't figure it out.

```
Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim rowstring As String
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Set view = db.GetView( nameofview )
Set vc = view.AllEntries
Set entry = vc.GetFirstEntry()

While Not entry Is Nothing 
    rowstring = ""
    Forall colval In entry.ColumnValues
        If rowstring = "" Then
            rowstring = colval
        Else
            rowstring = rowstring + +","  + colval
        End If          
    End Forall
Wend
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it accumulates the columns into rowval by converting the colval string into an numeric value. You could just as easily use double/CDbl() if they're floating point. This is assuming that, by "count the two columns", you mean sum them up and output the sum. If you mean literally count, then keep it as an `Integer` and change the line

```
rowval = rowval + CInt(colval)
```

to

```
rowval = rowval + 1
```

Here it is:

```
Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim rowval As Integer                       ' or Double '
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Set view = db.GetView( nameofview )
Set vc = view.AllEntries
Set entry = vc.GetFirstEntry()

While Not entry Is Nothing 
    rowval = 0
    Forall colval In entry.ColumnValues
        rowval = rowval + CInt(colval)      ' Or CDbl() '
    End Forall
    ' Output rowval here. '
    Set entry=vc.GetNextEntry (entry)
Wend
```

As per your original sample, I haven't output anything (?) but I've put a comment where you should do it.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry I should have been more specific because I meant sum of the two columns.  Ok, so does this mean the rowval is a two-celled array with both sums inside?  How do I have two integer variables equal to each sum?

Comment: I'm trying to email the each of the column sums.  I tried putting
    Call rtitem.AppendText ( rowval )
and the agent doesn't run all the way through.  Any thoughts as to why this would happen?
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In answer to your first, rowval is initialized for every row then it has colval added to it. Where it says "output rowval here", that's where you have to process rowval for that row just done.

Comment: In answer to (2), I've just noticed the infinite loop (which I copied from your original code) - see update just before Wend where it advances to next row.

Comment: Thank you it works!  I put in filesprocessed = filesprocessed + rowval in the ' Output rowval here. '.  This is what I don't understand.  I'd like to be able to sum up each column individually.  I tried specifying the first column by saying entry.ColumnValues(0) but it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Alrighty I figured it out!
While Not entry Is nothing
rowval = 0
errors = 0
Forall colval In entry.ColumnValues
If rowval > 0 Then
errors = Cint(colval)
Else
rowval = Cint(colval)
End if
End Forall
filesprocessed = filesprocessed + rowval
errorstotal = errorstotal + errors
etc

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add a column that sums the programmatic names of the other two columns and then put totals on it? Then a simple File - Export of the view is all that is needed.

Comment: @Peter, you don't always have control of the Notes DB schema, even if you can write agents for it.